# validate csv file upload with jquery-validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following code for upload form validation. I'm using jQuery validation plugin.

The `required: true` works fine, but `extension: "csv"` is not, and continue with submit.

Here's my code:

```
<form method="POST" action="uploadCoordenadas" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frm-upload" name="frm-upload">
  upload file:
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Procesar">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $("#frm-upload").validate({
    rules: {
      file: {
        required: true,
        extension: "csv"
      }
    },
    messages: {
      file: {
        required: "Debe seleccionar un archivo para realizar la carga.",
        extension: "Debe seleccionar un archivo con extension valida (*.csv)"
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include first the additional-methods.js file, because this rule is an extension.

Comment: No, I follow several examples without additional methods, like this: https://jqueryvalidation.org/extension-method/

Comment: See the js import in the link you provide : `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>`

Comment: You need to import both `jquery.validate.min.js` and `addit‌​ional-methods.min.js‌​`

Comment: Thanks! now it works!!!